# How to check presence of all three elements of list in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am new to Python and need some help on this

I have the following list of string

```
my_list = ["-Public-", "-Private-", "-Protected-"]
```

and another list

```
sgList = [ 'launch-wizard-16', 'launch-Private-1', 'default', 'EP-Protected-12', 'default', 'launch-Public-13']
```

I wanted to check if all the three elements from the `my_list` list are present in `sgList` if yes then return True otherwise False. If even one of them is not present then it should return false.

I have the following code but this will return True even if one of them is found.

```
imported = (any(rails.lower() in sg.lower() for rails in my_list for sg in sgList))
```

Can someone please guide me on what I can do here to check the presence of all three elements

Comment: `all(rails.lower() in sgList for rails in my_list)`

Comment: all isn’t going to directly work because I am looking at everything in sgList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `all` and `any`:

```py
my_list = ["-Public-", "-Private-", "-Protected-"]
sgList = ['launch-wizard-16', 'launch-Private-1', 'default', 'EP-Protected-12', 'default', 'launch-Public-13']

output = all(any(x in sg for sg in sgList) for x in my_list)
print(output) # True
```

Given `x == '-Public-'`, for example, `any(x in sg for sg in sgList)` tests if `'-Public-'` is a substring of any of the items in `sgList`. Since there is such an item (`'launch-Public-13'`), `any(x in sg for sg in sgList)` evaluates to `True`.

Now `all(... for x in my_list)` checks if this holds for every item `x` in `my_list`.

Comment: thank you can you please explain a bit on how this is working? combination of all/any

Answer (score 0):

```py
all(elem in sgList for elem in my_list)
```

where

- `... for elem in my_list` is an generator iterating over all elements in `my_list` and
- `elem in sgList` is a boolean expression checking if the iterated elements are actually in `sgList`, such that multiple `True` and `False` values are generated and
- eventually `all()` combines all the boolean expression into one, i.e. it is `True` if all are `True` (alternatively see `any()`)

Comment: all isn’t going to directly work because I am looking at everything in sgList

Comment: The clause `elem in sgList` will check if the element is anywhere in sgList, and then the all will return true if all elements of my_list are present anywhere in sgList. This does exactly what you want.

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.